# how to use listpicker selectionChanged event in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, listpicker

Am new to Wp7, developing the app with `ListPicker` and used `SelectionChanged` event to get selected data form listPicker but am having the problem with `SelectionChanged` event when am using this and getting `NullReferenceException` but when i used same code in `button_Click` that works perfectly and am getting the selected text

my c# code is :

```
 private void listPicker1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListPickerItem lpi = (ListPickerItem)listPicker1.SelectedItem;//this code is working in click event
        MessageBox.Show(lpi.Content.ToString());
    }
```

my Xaml code is

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listPicker1" Grid.Row="0" ExpansionMode="ExpansionAllowed" SelectionChanged="listPickerCountryLogin_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="436" FullModeHeader="Select Country" Background="White" BorderBrush="White">
            <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" Width="250" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
            <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" Width="300" Margin="0,0,0,20" FontSize="44"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

but i want to get the text form `SelectionChanged` event?

how to achive this :)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

am also ran into same problem am also getting `NullReferenceException`

Try this works fine for me

1) If you are using static `ListPickerItems` means without `DataBinding` use this

```
private void listPicker1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListPickerItem lpi = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem as ListPickerItem;
    MessageBox.Show("selected item is : " + lpi.Content);
}
```

2) Try this if You are using `DataBinding` to dispaly the `listPickerItems`

```
 private void listPicker1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     Countries item = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem as Countries;
     MessageBox.Show("Selected Item is : " + item.Country);
}
```

here am assuming that you prepared a class `Countries` with `country` property for taht you need to typeCast to selected item to Countries class then only you get the result

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. However it seems the SelectionChanged event is fired when the application is loaded. So I used this checking
if (ListPicker1.SelectedItem != null)
{put your codes}

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem when using SelectionChanged event in my listpicker, here is what I had:

```
// My listpicker is LpBluetoothPaired

 private void LpBluetoothPaired_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

         rcvData.Text = LpBluetoothPaired.SelectedItem.ToString();

    }
```

But when opening the app it had an exception, so I fixed it:

```
 private void LpBluetoothPaired_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

       if (LpBluetoothPaired.SelectedItem != null) {
            rcvData.Text = LpBluetoothPaired.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
    }
```

it looks like the event is called when the application is opening but at that time there is still no selectedItem, so in order to avoid the exception and only fulfill the rcvData textBox I check if it isn''t null

Comment: This didn't work for me, however when I used SelectedItem.Content.ToString(), it worked

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes SelectionChanged event fires, when setting the ItemsSource from code behind. So, in such case the selectedItem may be null.

Hence, add this line in your SelectionChanged code and try.

```
private void listPicker1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(listPicker1.SelectedIndex == -1) //otherwise (listPicker1.SelectedItem == null) also works
    return;
    ListPickerItem lpi = (ListPickerItem)listPicker1.SelectedItem;//this code is working in click event
    MessageBox.Show(lpi.Content.ToString());
}
```

If still problem persists, place a break point in the SelectionChanged handler, and observe the values

Comment: on page loading `SelectedIndex` value is set to 0 not -1 and null so retutn statement is not exicuted :(

Comment: you could check if(listPicker1.SelectedItem == null) ... I mentioned this in the answer as well

Comment: yeah am checked with null also and am getting invalid cast exception for this `ListPickerItem lpi = (ListPickerItem)listPicker1.SelectedItem;`

Comment: am checked with that `null` also am getting invalid cast exception any idea ? where i went wrong

Comment: show your ListPicker Xaml code also in the question, that may give a clear idea about the issue

Answer (score 0):

When data is loading to the listpicker it fires selectionchanged event.So for this put your code in Try-catch and For selectionchanged write this :

```
private void listPicker1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
        Countries SelectedCountries =e.AddedItems[0] as Countries;
        String SelectedCountry = SelectedCountries.Country;
     }
     catch
     {
     }
}
```